# Setting Cancel button on uiactionsheet causes last item to disappear

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet, dynamically-generated, cancel-button

I am dynamically adding buttons to my uiactionsheet.  I end with adding a "Cancel" button, but if I either use the method setCancelButtonIndex or manually set the index, "Cancel" does not show.  If I exclude the setCancelButtonIndex call, Cancel is there (without the highlight, of course).  Is there a footnote I've missed?

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"What do you want to do?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
for (NSString *title in arrayButtons) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:[arrayButtons count]-1];
[actionSheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:0];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `-addButtonWithTitle:` returns the button index. So you should do in this way:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
[actionSheet setTitle:@"What do you want to do?"];
[actionSheet setDelegate:self];
for (NSString *title in arrayButtons) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}
[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"]];     
[actionSheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:0];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"]];
but with no success.
I just tried your exact code and it has the same problem.

Comment: @NelsonKo I just edited my answer with the sample code.

Comment: To me, everything makes sense (and to some degree equal).  I've used your code and the same thing happens.  Can't figure out what the difference is.

Comment: Is there a string `@"Cancel"` inside `arrayButtons`? If so, try removing it.

Comment: I dynamically build the array based on various conditions.  None of the elements include @"Cancel".  @LeoFormaggio, I feel I'm taking advantage of your perseverance, but I thank you for it!

Comment: @NelsonKo You're welcome! But, unfortunately, I don't have any idea on what's happening. All my `UIActionSheet` implementations, even with dynamic button titles, are done like this and works great. Consider adding static button titles to wee what happens.

Comment: Oddly, if I add one more dummy button, the @"Cancel" button appears, indicating that setting the cancel button decreases the number of buttons by one.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by adding `[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:nil];` after adding all other buttons. Now all buttons appear in the action sheet.